# Shell scripts with sequential input files in background

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

There are 3 scripts, expA, expB ,and expC on my Linux server (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).
Then , I got 32 input files named as nctu_0, nctu_1 ..... nctu_31. Six of them are much larger them others, so I take 3 input files for expA, 3 for expB, and the other for expC.

i.e.
expA: run nctu_6 nctu_13 nctu_17
,expB: run nctu_20 nctu_24 nctu_31
,expC: run the other files

Here is the original script of expB, and the script of expA is almost the same as expB

```
#!/bin/bash
PROGRAM=./Simulator
FILE_PART_PREFIX1=/home//data/pcap_partial/h1200/nctu_
RESULT_PREFIX1=/home/data/setup_exp/h1200
RECEIVER_SIZE=4096
SENDER_SIZE=4096
BETA=0.25
UPDATE=400
MARKER=20
part=20
if [ ${part} -eq 20 ];then
nohup ${PROGRAM} 1 ${FILE_PART_PREFIX1}${part}.pcap ${RECEIVER_SIZE} ${SENDER_SIZE}    ${BETA} ${UPDATE} ${MARKER} ${MODE} >> ${RESULT_PREFIX1}/res_${part} 2>&1 &
fi
part=24
if [ ${part} -eq 24 ];then
nohup ${PROGRAM} 1 ${FILE_PART_PREFIX1}${part}.pcap ${RECEIVER_SIZE} ${SENDER_SIZE}   ${BETA} ${UPDATE} ${MARKER} ${MODE} >> ${RESULT_PREFIX1}/res_${part} 2>&1 &
fi
part=31
if [ ${part} -eq 31 ];then
nohup ${PROGRAM} 1 ${FILE_PART_PREFIX1}${part}.pcap ${RECEIVER_SIZE} ${SENDER_SIZE} ${BETA} ${UPDATE} ${MARKER} ${MODE} >> ${RESULT_PREFIX1}/res_${part} 2>&1 &
fi
```

I want to run nctu_20 first, then run nctu_24 after nctu_24 is done. At last run nctu_31 after nctu_24 is done.

---

Here is the original script of expC

```
#!/bin/bash
PROGRAM=./Simulator
FILE_PART_PREFIX1=/home/data/pcap_partial/h1200/nctu_
RESULT_PREFIX1=/home/data/setup_exp/h1200
RECEIVER_SIZE=4096
SENDER_SIZE=4096
BETA=0.25
UPDATE=400
MARKER=20
for (( part=0;part<32;part=part+1 ))
do
if [ ${part} -eq 6 ] || [ ${part} -eq 13 ] || [ ${part} -eq 17 ] || [ ${part} -eq 20 ] ||[ ${part} -eq 24 ] || [ ${part} -eq 31 ];then
continue
else
nohup ${PROGRAM} 1 ${FILE_PART_PREFIX1}${part}.pcap ${RECEIVER_SIZE} ${SENDER_SIZE} ${BETA} ${UPDATE} ${MARKER} ${MODE} >> ${RESULT_PREFIX1}/res_${part} 2>&1 &
fi
done
```

In brief, I want to run expA, expB expC at the same time and each of them launch a simulator program with a sequential input file in the background. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I've understood well what you need, but if you want to run them simultaneously, I don't think bash can help you. You should write a wrapper in some other languages that supports threads, here is in example in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub start_simulator {
   my $simulator = shift;
   system("./$simulator");
}

my $thA = threads->create('start_simulator', 'expA');
$thA->detach();

my $thB = threads->create('start_simulator', 'expB');
$thB->detach();

my $thC = threads->create('start_simulator', 'expC');
$thC->detach();

exit 0;
```

Add this wrapper inside the same directory where you have your shell script and run it with `./perl_wrapper.pl`.